# Success function is not working in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var url = 'https://localhost/api/v1/courses?access_token=1~SyKlbGwJhrAQ5uhq8ybCBHpZtestOIbFErUHMo0fDk3PJhI3PuNbW1Jz0inm21nR';
$.ajax(url, {  
    dataType: "jsonp",  
    data: "count=5",  
    success: function (data) {  
        alert(data);  
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Here success function is not working but I am getting in the response in the `error` function isthis  :

```
{ 
    "readyState": 4,
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "success"
}
```

How can I get data in the `success` function?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: I doubt the server code, check it to know how the error message is given

Comment: this is api so i just mention localhost for post here...

Comment: Also try doing:
success: function(data){ console.log(data); }

Comment: i am using jquery 1.7.1 version

Comment: nothing coming if i try you said

Comment: Alerts suck. console.log or console.debug will give you much more indepth analysis of the problem. Also try something like this:

success:function(data){
    try { console.log("data: ", data); } catch(err){ console.log("Err: ", err); }
}

Comment: Have you tried using $.post(); or $.get(); //that will work I guess

Comment: Oh and btw you have to have your debug console open to read the console logs. Firefox has Firebug, Chrome/Safari has developer tools, etc, then just click on the "Console" tab

Comment: i am using firebug dude...it is not showing only for this request...

Answer (score 0):

```
error: function() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

to see all the arguments passed to the error function.

---

You have stated `dataType: "jsonp"`, but have not specified any callback in your url.

If the data you expect is just plain json, you should use `dataType: "json"`.

In any case, the `error` can be triggered if the server successfully returned an answer, but the answer doesn't conform to the expected format (e.g : invalid json, error when executing final jsonp statement ...).